# Retrieving result from JSON to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following  JSON-
[image]

1. journeys

   - `{obj} 0`

     - [ ] legs

       - {obj} 0

         - {obj} instruction
         - "string" detailed : string value goes here0
       - {obj} 1

         - {obj} instruction
         - "string" detailed : string value goes here1
   - `{obj} 1`

     - [ ] legs

       - {obj} 0

         - {obj} instruction
         - "string" detailed : string value goes here0
       - {obj} 1

         - {obj} instruction
         - "string" detailed : string value goes here1
   - `{obj} 2`

     - [ ] legs

       - {obj} 0

         - {obj} instruction
         - "string" detailed : string value goes here0
       - {obj} 1

         - {obj} instruction
         - "string" detailed : string value goes here1

My plan is to iterate through values "journeys" and store them in an `ArrayList`. Similarly, store "legs" in another `ArrayList` and finally get retrieve the value for the object `instruction`. As you can see parent `journeys` has 3 child `{obj} 0`, `{obj} 1`, `{obj} 2`. I can get the `journeys` stored using --

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> journey = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<JSONArray> leg = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<JSONObject> legDetails = new ArrayList<>();

try {
            JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("journeys");
            if (jArray != null) {
                for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    journey.add(jArray.getJSONObject(i));
                }
                if (!journey.isEmpty()){
                    for (int j=0;j<journey.size();j++){
                         leg.add(journey.get(j).getJSONArray("legs"));
                }
            }
            if (!leg.isEmpty()){
                for (int i = 0; i<leg.size();i++){
                     legDetails.add(leg.get(i).getJSONObject(i));
                    }
            }
          }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now each journey returns 2 legs and the number changes time to time. I was expecting 6 `JSONObject` at the end of last `for` loop but I only get 2 and a out of range exception.

Things to remember: Journey has Routes (Obj 0,1,2). Routes has legs (Obj 0,1). Legs consists of `instruction` with `detail` string.

Is this right approach to retrieve the value? and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is here

```
        if (!journey.isEmpty()){

          for (int j=0;j<journey.size();j++){
                   leg.add(journey.get(j).getJSONArray("legs"));

                }

        }
```

journery's have 3 objects.

```
for j=0 you add journey[0] array to leg
for j=1 you add journey[1] array to leg
for j=2 you add journey[2] array to leg
```

so legs will have 3 arrays.

```
if (!leg.isEmpty()){
   for (int i = 0; i<leg.size();i++){
      legDetails.add(leg.get(i).getJSONObject(i));
   }
}
```

here leg.size()=3;

```
for i=0 it will add leg[0]'s [0]th element
for i=1 it will add leg[1]'s [1]th element
for i=2 it will add leg[2]'s [2]th element (this is out of range)
```

update ::

```
if (!leg.isEmpty()){
   for (int i = 0; i<leg.size();i++){
      for(int j=0;j<leg.get(i).size();j++)
         legDetails.add(leg.get(i).getJSONObject(j));
   }
}
```

This should help

Comment: Thanks.. I understand this but can't solve it.. How can I go about and retrieve the `instruction` value?

Comment: Awesome! But is there another way to store them as key value pairs?